# groovy - findAll getting only one value

Tags: groovy

I'm struggling to find examples of findAll with groovy. I've got a very
simple code snippet that gets the property of a node and outputs it's
value. Except I'm only getting the last value when I'm looping through
a series of properties. Is there something I'm doing wrong here, this
seems really simple.

```
JcrUtils.getChildNodes("footer").findAll{ 
 selectFooterLabel = it.hasProperty("footerLabel") ? it.getProperty("footerLabel").getString() : ""
}
```

In my jsp I'm just printing the property:

```
<%=selectFooterLabel%>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe `selectFooterLabel` is being re-assigned each time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findAll` returns a `List` containing all the items in the original list for which the closure returns a Groovy-true value (boolean true, non-empty string/map/collection, non-null anything else).  It looks like you probably wanted `collect`

```
def footerLabels = JcrUtils.getChildNodes("footer").collect{ 
 it.hasProperty("footerLabel") ? it.getProperty("footerLabel").getString() : ""
}
```

which will give you a List of the values returned by the closure.  If you then want only the subset of those that are not empty you can use `findAll()` with no closure parameter, which gives you the subset of values from the list that are themselves Groovy-true

```
def footerLabels = JcrUtils.getChildNodes("footer").collect{ 
 it.hasProperty("footerLabel") ? it.getProperty("footerLabel").getString() : ""
}.findAll()
```

Comment: Thanks! Was there a specific reason you removed selectFooterLabel inside of collect?

Comment: @DelmonYoung because it obscures what the code is actually doing.  The `collect` method "collects" the values returned by the closure when called for each element of the original list.  Putting an assignment inside the closure isn't right, what matters is what the closure _returns_.